# Python Converter XLS (2003) para XLSX

Tags: java, c#, python, microsoft-excel

Bom Dia!

Galera, tenho um diretório com diversas planilhas exportadas do meu sistema no formato XLS (Formato Excel 97 - 2003), preciso escrever um script para percorrer esse diretório e converter essas planilhas para XLSX. As bibliotecas XLDR e Openpyxl não conseguem abir minhas planilhas, devido ao formato.

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda, ou indicar alguma biblioteca?

Aceito dicas em C# e Java também

Comment: Com C# você pode [usarSpire.XLS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.XLS/): 
`workbook.LoadFromFile("Input.xls");`
`workbook.SaveToFile("Output.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013);`

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution
I required a simple solution to convert couple of xlx to xlsx format. There are plenty of answers here, but they are doing some "magic" that I do not completely understand.

A simple solution was given by chfw, but not quite complete.

> Install dependencies Use pip to install

```
pip install pyexcel-cli pyexcel-xls pyexcel-xlsx
```

Execute
All the styling and macros will be gone, but the information is intact.

For single file

```
pyexcel transcode your-file-in.xls your-new-file-out.xlsx
```

For all files in the folder, one liner

```
for file in *.xls; do; echo "Transcoding $file"; pyexcel transcode "$file" "${file}x";

 done;
```

Comment: Fabio, este site é o [pt.so]. Por favor clique em **[edit]** e traduza a resposta...